# Why WPF Dependency Prop. designed to call OnPropertyChangedCallback instead of firing event?

Tags: wpf

I'm wondering why MS decided to call OnPropertyChangedCallback instead of firing some kind of event.

Is there any rationale behind this?
To me, raising events inside OnPropertyChangedCallback seems to add more code to write, and doesn't seem to have much performance benefits.
But I'd like to know if there are some edge cases / usage benefits that I might have missed (preferably with code examples).

Thank you : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking MS use a convention that events should be raised by the method called On*EventName*. See this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx). Thanks to that every developer knows how to raise a given event and doesn't have to write his own code to do so.

It is a pretty simple code but there is no need to copy&paste it and clutter the source code. You have to remember that a given event can be raised in many places. It is true regardless if we talk about WPF, WinForms or any other technology.

By the way, I tried to find `OnPropertyChangedCallback` in [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=OnPropertyChangedCallback) and I din't find it.

Comment: hm... I'm reading Pro WPF 4.5 using c#, and I guess this is some error on the book. I couldn't find OnPropertyChangedCallback on MSDN either. Anyway, thanks for the answer : )